# Nesting element+element selector in SCSS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

As a newbie in SCSS I am wondering how to use its nesting for the *[element + element](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)* selector of CSS. Normally, in CSS, I would write something like:

```
.test{
    color: red;
}
.test + label{
    color: blue;
}
```

How can I nest the `+ label` selector inside the `.test` selector? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upate:** In this case all you need to do is to nest rules like this:

```css
.test {
    color: red;
    + label {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

However, you can also use the `&` selector to achieve the same effect like this:

```
.test {
    color: red;
    & +label {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, this worked like a charm!

Comment: You don't even need the & there.

Comment: @BoltClock how do u mean?

Comment: @Angelos Chalaris: `+ label`

Comment: @BoltClock so like `.test{ color:red; +label { color:blue; } }`? If so, what is the difference and which one is safer/better/more consistent with the way people write or are supposed to write SCSS?

Comment: @Angelos Chalaris: Yes. There is no difference and it's entirely personal preference whether or not you include it. The & works, but it's not absolutely needed despite what this answer implies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification @BoltClock!

Comment: Totally true, you don't need `&` in this case. It's my bad. You would use `&` in cases when you want to address selectors that belongs to the same element. For example, for `<div class="a b"></dib>`: `.a { &.b {} }`.